# Calling a different java app from within java app

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I need to secure the connection between my primary java app and my MYSQL server. Right now I have a class in my primary java app with the info about my SQL server (login details; user, password, schema etc).

I tried obfuscating that class but it didn't succeed. Then I heard something about calling an external java app with the connection info, and retrieve that info securely.

How can I execute such a thing?

Comment: What makes you think that would any more secure? Even with a SSL connection, its still possible to intercept and decode the stream (sure it's more difficult but given the fact that the information is likely to be the same each time you request the info, the chances increases)

Comment: I understand that. But all I want is the connection class to be either out of the app or invisible in the .jar.

Comment: Is the database server localized to the client machine or running on a remote server?

Comment: Remove server on a webhost.

Answer (score 0):

```
                 Runtime run;
                 Process pr = null;                    
                 run = Runtime.getRuntime();
         pr = run.exec("your program.jar"); 
         pr.getInputStream().close();
         InputStream eos = pr.getErrorStream();
```

and you can use a file to pass your info to the jar application

Comment: That requires the user to have the other app on their computer?

Comment: the application must be in their computer

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with a client/server style application, all the business logic, including the persistence layer, should be maintained on the server side.

That is, the client connects to some server process and makes requests.  It should never care about how the data is managed or stored.  It just cares about getting and manipulating the data.  This also means that you centralise the business associated with that data, which means that should it change, you are less likely to need to change the client.

This also means that all the access information for the database never leaves the domain of the server.

Now the question is, how do you achieve.  This answer will come down to exactly what it is you want to achieve an the means by which you want to achieve it, but, I would also add, the client should be authenticating with the server first, meaning that the user must be made to enter and user name and password in order to be able access the data (unless it's a public accessible API, then you probably don't care).

### You could use

[RMI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/).  This would allow you to expose server objects that the client could interact with.  This is good if you wish to send objects from the server to the client.  It allows the client to interact with Java objects as if they were local objects.

From a coding point of view, this is a (relatively) simple solution, as you are dealing with Java Objects.  The problem is though, only Java clients (with the right libraries) will be able to access the server.

### You could use

Plain [Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/).  This will allow you to connect to a service on the server and communicate with it.

You can even serialize objects between the client and server, allow the application to deal with Java Objects as well.

This is also a much more difficult approach, as you become responsible for dealing with the low level protocol and error handling (which RMI takes care of for you).

This approach does, however, provide you with the opportunity for other clients to connect to your server (so long as you are using just a plain sockets and serializing objects ;)).

This is a lot of work...

### You could use

Some kind of web service (Servlet's under Tomcat for example or event a J2EE server), that would use simple HTTP requests to list of available services/functions that would return either something like JSON or XML response which the client would then need to parse.

This is, by far, the most open and probably the most common solution.  It would take some work to get running, but is far less involved then using something like sockets and is also the most flexible, as you wouldn't need release no libraries each time you want to change or update a service.

Now all these allow you to provide secure connections over the wire, through SSL, you just need to establish the correct connection from the client to the server, so you've got an added level of security.

Each hides the database access behind a server layer, adding additional protection to the database.

Comment: Can I use the third option with a webhost (with CPanel)?

Comment: You'll have to parse the result back to a format that you want to use, so yes, it should be doable